# Парсинг XML с помощью MSXML

Tags: c++, xml, парсер, windows-10

*Давно не кодил на C++ и многое уже подзабыл.*

Использую Visual Studio 2019. Пытаюсь создать XML-документ из строки:

```
#import "msxml3.dll"
#include <MsXml2.h>

using namespace MSXML2;

int main()
{
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr spXMLDoc;
    spXMLDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument30));
    spXMLDoc->load("<Parent></Parent>");

    spXMLDoc.Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Но в run-time бросает исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756987(v%3Dvs.85) посмотрите пример с++, пока навскидку видно отсутствие `CoInitialize` и `CoCreateInstance`

Comment: Здесь показано, как это сделать: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43309/How-to-create-a-simple-XML-file-using-MSXML-in-C

Comment: вам обязательно использовать MSXML? Если нет, то по-моему любая сторонняя библиотека будет лучше

Comment: @PavelGridin, это легаси проект и приходиться использовать существующее. Но Вы задали хороший вопрос. Я и сам задавался вопросом зачем тут в плюсах использовали COM, он вроде как медленнее любой нативной библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу здесь три ошибки.
Во-первых, как сказал goldstar_labs, необходимо инициализировать COM. Я использую объект - инициализатор:

```
struct _Init {
    bool m_binitialized = false;
    _Init() {
        _com_util::CheckError(::CoInitialize(NULL));
        m_binitialized = true;
    }
    ~_Init() {
        if(m_binitialized)
            CoUninitialize();
    }
} _init;
```

Во-вторых, `#include <MsXml2.h>` не нужен, более того, мешает - достаточно `#import "msxml3.dll"`. Единственно, компилятор почему-то не всегда сразу создаёт tlh/tli файлы, лечил так: в свойствах проекта линкеру в секцию Input->Additional Dependencies добавить "msxml3.dll", запустить компиляцию, затем убрать (если кто знает более прямой путь, поправьте). С msxml6.dll такой трюк не потребовался.

И в-третьих, для загрузки XML непосредственно из аргумента изпользуется метод loadXML(), а использованный вами load() загружает из файла.

P.S. Я создавал инстанс документа так:

```
_com_util::CheckError(pXmlCfg.CreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument));
```